# Why the dot in the middle of a path?

Tags: shell-script, filenames

Every now and then I see some command to run a shell script that looks something like this:

`~/foo/bar/baz/./script.sh`

Now, I know that in general you need a `./` to tell Linux to look in your current directory for executables. But what's the point of saying "go to this folder, then go there again, then execute a file?"

Comment: It isn't wrong, but it is redundant. Is it possible that the path was autogenerated in the scripts where you see this?

Comment: almost definitely the automated result of pasting a directory and a filename with the leading `./` -- it's a feature, not an accident, that this results in a valid path construct

Comment: Interestingly enough is there any overhead in having the ./ there? What if there were several hundred chained together? Or thousands. Is the OS or interpreter smart enough to ignore or truncate them?

Comment: @MikeMcMahon Not sure how the final part of the path parser is implemented, but i expect either no-change operations in a state machine or skip-this operations in a tree builder; so i would think that it would sum down to the cost of "if ".", NEXT".

Comment: @MikeMcMahon If you're not already making pathnames one character long as a necessary optimization, I'd say you shouldn't worry about it. All processed data has a cost, both memory and computation: that extra `./` takes up a couple extra bytes, and any work done on the path must iterate/loop over those bytes and do at least one logical comparison on them. Some cost goes into the decision and actions needed to ignore/truncate. But I think the realistic cost is a handful of CPU instructions, branch predictor misses, and a few bytes of memory and CPU cache, on average. Still extremely negligible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference. Executing the following:

```
~foo/bar/baz/./script.sh
```

and

```
~foo/bar/baz/script.sh
```

will have the same effect.

Comment: This is also the case with '//' in a path. I've done that in scripts by accident as well.

Comment: not if script.sh parses $0...

Comment: @user208145 Unless the `//` is at the start of the path. I believe that causes it to be treated as a network path.

Comment: @JAB only in cygwin, afaik, linuxdom doesn't use that.

Comment: @StarWeaver Ah, you're right. I was thinking of https://superuser.com/a/389345/45130, which just says that some shells preserve those paths to be compatible with that behavior.

Comment: @JAB @StarWeaver The POSIX standard allows a starting `//` to be special on any system. (But not any longer sequences, `///` and so on are required to be equal to just `/`.) So if you care about portability to Cygwin and a few obscure proprietary Unixes, it's worth considering. But your typical Linux or BSD system combined with your typical shell will not treat it specially.

Comment: @mtraceur hmm, interesting. Only other thing i know of is that blender uses // starting paths for "relative to current file" (presumably at some point having that and working directory both available was useful?), but blender isn't an OS or OS-like thing. (Also how do you @ more than one person, it literally won't let me post with that…)

Comment: @StarWeaver Yeah, I think Blender overloaded `//` in their own strange way because they knew it was allowed to be special anyway. I'm not sure about the multiple-@: It just works for me. Only thing I can think of is that I browse with NoScript enabled, and only allow the main https://{foo}.stackexchange.com, https:// stackoverflow.com, and https:// cdn.sstatic.com domains. Maybe the code that's preventing multi-@ is sourced from a different sub-domain and I've never noticed? I also just typed the @ and usernames as I saw them in the preceding comments - I didn't use the autocomplete feature.

Comment: @mtraceur Huh, yeah, i'@ using the phone app usually which is about as far from noscript as you can get